# unable to deploy application on cloudfoundry raising error 404 Not Found

Tags: cloud-foundry, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, vmc

i am trying to deploy spring application on cloudfoundry.but as a build war file of project using mvn package command.after that i used vmc push --appname target(directory)
i finished all the steps that need to push on cloudfoundry.
finally i got message uploading application-name....ok
then i entered command vmc apps
then it shows all my pushed applications....
there was url(http://cloudapp-project-master.cloudfoundry.com/) for my deployed application.
which i copied and placed in browser then it giving me 404 Not Found nginx
i don't know where is the problem....
Please help me to get out of this.
advanced thanks....

Comment: Opening a support ticket would be a good idea. Alternatively, you can a) collect the logs with "vmc logs <appname>", or deploy from STS and watch the status unfold as the app deploys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you look at the logs folder to see if the files there give more information.

```
vmc logs <app-name>
```

or

```
vmc files <app-name> logs/stderr.log
vmc files <app-name> logs/stdout.log
```

Comment: in my directory of project there is no logs folder and also i have not yet recieved cloudfountry ip or domain name....help me

Answer (score 0):

What is the status of the app when you run vmc apps? I would recommend you to file a ticket at http://support.cloudfoundry.com with detailed information about the issue and maybe share the project so that they can reproduce the issue easily. You will need the account registered in cf.com to be able to login.

Comment: status is Running !!!!!! already i recieved password for my mail id . iam deploying on that credintials.can u tell what are the steps